# what's the regular expression to find two sets of parenthesis in a row using perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have rows with different sets of parenthesis. For example

```
     (sdfsfs) (sfdsfd) 
     (sdfsfs) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd) 
     (sdfsfs) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd)
     (sdfsfs) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd)
     (sdfsfs) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd) (sfdsfd)
```

What's the regular expression to find only rows with two sets of parenthesis? In my example above, the first row.

When the try this regular expression

```
/\(.*\) \(.*\)/
```

its returning all the rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to match a line with exactly 2 parentheses sets:

```
m/^(\([^)]*\)\s*){2}$/
```

OR:

```
m/^\([^)]*\)\s*\([^)]*\)$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pP0xG2/1)

`[^)]*` will match any character but `)` and is more efficient than `.*?` or `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better solution.

```
while ( $text =~ //(?m)^(?=(?:.*?(?&parens)){2})(?!(?:.*?(?&parens)){3}).+$(?(DEFINE)(?<parens>\([^)\n]*\)))/g )
{
    print $&,"\n";
}
```

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^                             # BOL
 (?=                           # Must be 2 paren's blocks
      (?:
           .*? (?&parens) 
      ){2}
 )
 (?!                           # Cannot be 3 paren's blocks
      (?:
           .*? (?&parens) 
      ){3}
 )
 .+                            # Get the entire line
 $                             # EOL

 (?(DEFINE)
      (?<parens> \( [^)\n]* \) )    # (1)
 )
```

Comment: @HåkonHægland  - Not really. Its fully constrained. Must be minimum 2 blocks, cannot be 3 or more. Basically its `if ( x >= 2 && x < 3 ), _x_ must equal 2`

Comment: Yes I realized that, so I deleted my comment.. When you say this is a better solution, are you referring to the other answers?

Comment: @HåkonHægland  - Absolutely. Leaving it here for brevity. Somebody will get something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\s*\([^\)(]*\)\s*){2}$
```

You can define this pattern with anchors.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/10