# missing last character in perl regex

Tags: perl

(log doggies) (log needs)

```
^\(log (.*)[^)]\)\s*\(log (.*)[^)]\)$
```

It works with the exception of missing character at the end "s" as:

doggie
need

Comment: Iterative coding assistance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055326/how-to-capture-text-within-a-negate-class-character-using-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949142/whats-the-regular-expression-to-find-two-sets-of-parenthesis-in-a-row-using-per May I direct you to http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618 to learn more about regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
^\(log (.*)\)\s*\(log (.*)\)$
```

You don't need to negate the `)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `[^)]` eats your `s`-es. Why do you need it?

```
my $s = '(log doggies) (log needs)';
say for $s =~ /^\(log (.*)\)\s*\(log (.*)\)$/;
```

Output:

```
doggies
needs
```

Comment: I need the [^)] to make sure it search for two consecutive sets of parenthesis and not three or four or .etc.

Comment: Do you need to use (.*)? If you're only concerned about alphanumeric characters you can use (\w*).

Comment: @BruceWalker: Then please show the input that shows why you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `.*` should be `[^)]*`, i.e. *any number of characters that are not closing parentheses. Giving

```
^\(log ([^)]*)\)\s*\(log ([^)]*)\)$
```

Or you could fetch all instances of `(log xxx)` with

```
while ( $s =~ /\(log ([^)]*)\)/g ) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```